# Do products preserve colimits in the category of locales?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits, locales

Does the functor $X\times-:\mathbf{Loc}\to\mathbf{Loc}$ preserve small colimits for all locales $X$?

---

The reason that I'm interested in this question is that the same property [fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969372/simple-example-of-product-not-preserving-coequaliser-in-mathbftop) in the category of topological spaces. If products preserve colimits in a total category then it must be cartesian closed. The category $\mathbf{Top}$ is total, but fails to be cartesian closed because products don't preserve colimits. So it would be curious if $\mathbf{Loc}$ failed to be cartesian closed for the complementary reason. It's not total, so maybe products do preserve colimits in $\mathbf{Loc}$?

Another reason to ask this question is that the definition of "locale" requires precisely that products preserve colimits in its frame of opens. So it would be interesting if this property was mirrored at the category level.

Answer (score 2):

No, $- \times L$ does not preserve colimits for all locales $L$. Let $\Omega : Sob \leftrightarrows Loc : pt$ be the adjunction which embeds $Sob$ as a coreflective subcategory of $Loc$. I will give an example of when this is not true for spatial locales.

Let $f,g : X \to Y$ be continuous maps, $c : Y \to Z$ their coequalizer. Suppose that $X,Y,Z$ are locally compact Hausdorff spaces and $A$ is a Hausdorff space such that $- \times A$ does not preserve this coequalizer; that is, $c \times 1_A$ is not a coequalizer of $f \times 1_A$ and $g \times 1_A$. Then applying $\Omega$, we have the following commutative diagram:

[image]

where the vertical maps are the induced maps $(\Omega proj_1, \Omega proj_2)$, which are all isomorphisms since $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are locally compact. Since $\Omega$ is a left adjoint, we know that $\Omega c$ is a coequalizer of $\Omega f$ and $\Omega g$. By natural isomorphism then, the bottom row is a coequalizer diagram (that is, $- \times \Omega A$ preserves the coequalizer) if and only if the top row is. But $\Omega$ is fully faithful, hence it reflects (co)limits. So if the top row were a coequalizer, then $c \times 1_A$ would be a coequalizer of $f \times 1_A$ and $g \times 1_A$, contradicting our choice of $A$. Thus, the bottom row is not an equalizer, so $- \times \Omega A$ does not preserve all colimits.

Of course, it remains to produce an example which attains these conditions. It will be easiest to produce an example of a quotient map $p : Y \to Z$ between locally compact Hausdorff spaces for which $p \times 1_A$ is not a quotient map for some Hausdorff space $A$; this arises as the coequalizer of $f,1_Y : (Y, \tau_{discrete}) \to Y$ where $f$ contracts fibers of $p$ to a single point (in particular, $Y$ with the discrete topology is locally compact Hausdorff). I asked for such an example yesterday [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4771274/1221569); you can read the answer there for an example. The examples in [Bi-quotient maps and cartesian products of quotient maps](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_1968__18_2_287_0/), also references in the MSE answer, give some other examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think so? But I'm putting together results I don't understand in much detail. Let's try the following:

Equivalently the question is whether taking coproduct with a frame $X$ preserves limits of frames. We'll write the coproduct of frames as $\otimes$, since it turns out to coincide with the tensor product of suplattices (see [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tychonoff+theorem+for+locales#frames_and_the_category_of_suplattices) and [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suplattice)). The tensor product of suplattices has right adjoint given by the hom suplattice, so preserves colimits of suplattices in both variables; I *think* this implies that it preserves limits in both variables, because I think limits of suplattices can be computed as colimits and vice versa (e.g. products are coproducts); this is the step I'm least confident in. If that's true, then because limits of frames are computed as limits of suplattices (which in turn are computed as limits of underlying sets), tensor product preserves limits.

At the very least I'm confident that tensor product preserves products, so it remains to check if it preserves equalizers, which maybe can be done by hand.

Comment: Could it be that $(\mathbf{Sup},\otimes)$ is compact closed? Then it would be obvious that $X\otimes -$ preserves limits, since it would be left and right adjoint to $X^*\otimes -$. I've found some sources that refer to "dualizable suplattices" which suggests that they think there exist some nondualizable suplattices, but I can't find an example of such.

Comment: One point in favour of the idea that $\mathbf{Sup}$ is compact closed is the fact that it's the Eilenberg-Moore category of the monad for which the Kleisli category is $\mathbf{Rel}$, a classic example of a compact closed category. Even if $\mathbf{Sup}$ isn't compact closed we might be able to use the relationship with $\mathbf{Rel}$ to prove that $X\otimes -$ preserves limits.

Comment: Separately, how do you know that limits of frames are computed as limits of suplattices? Is there a left adjoint to $U:\mathbf{Frame}\to\mathbf{Sup}$?

Comment: @Oscar: oof, I'm not at all confident of the shaky step above anymore, but I'm a bit more confident that limits of frames are computed as limits of suplattices, because they're both computed as limits of sets, because they're both monadic over $\text{Set}$. But I do in addition believe that the forgetful functor from frames to suplattices has a left adjoint, and moreover I believe that it's monadic, basically because I believe frames are the models of a particular algebraic theory over suplattices (idempotent commutative monoids or something).

Comment: Are you sure of your argument?! If $X \times \_$ is continuous, $X$ is exponentiable. Unfortunately, not any locale is exponentiable: https://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0089910.

Comment: @Ivan: I'm not at all sure, which is why I said "I think so?" and "oof, I'm not at all confident." But Oscar did say in the OP that $\text{Loc}$ isn't total, so one can't apply the total form of the adjoint functor theorem. In general it's not enough to ask that $X \times (-)$ preserve colimits for $X$ to be exponentiable; the adjoint functor theorem always has extra conditions.

Comment: $\mathbf{Sup}$ isn't compact closed. The double-dual of $\{\{a,b,c\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{\}\}$ is $\{\{a,b,c,d,e\},\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,d\},\{b,d\},\{c,d\},\{d\},\{\}\}$.

Comment: @OscarCunningham How is the double-dual of the five element set you give the one above? The duality functor takes each suplattice to the same set with the opposite order, right? Maybe I simply do not understand the notation ...

Comment: In this context, the duality functor takes a sup-lattice to the set of sup-lattice morphisms to the two element sup-lattice (in the same way that the dual of a vector space is the set of linear maps from it to the field of scalars).