# Interpreting a homotopy as a function from $[0,1]$ to a function space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. A homotopy is a continuous $H:X\times[0,1]\to Y$. Currying, we get $H:[0,1]\to X\to Y$. Is there a way to interpret $H$ as a continuous function of type $H:[0,1]\to (X\to Y)$, where $(X\to Y)$ is the space of continuous function from $X$ to $Y$?

There are a few questions.

- Given topological spaces $X,Y$, is there natural space of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$?
- Given a function out of a product space $f:X\times Y\to Z$, is there a natural way to curry?
- If the above doesn't work for general spaces, is it possible for $Y=[0,1]$?

Comment: I think https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123950/is-top-provably-not-cartesian-closed is relevant: some restrictions on $X$ and $Y$ are required to get everything to work nicely. (Please ignore the pointless exchange of comments with someone who didn't understand the question.)

Comment: @RobArthan that doesn't seem to be quite what is being asked above. Extremeaxe5, what does 'natural' mean to you? For instance if you give $C(X,Y)=(X\rightarrow Y)$ the indiscrete topology, then any continuous function $Z\times X\rightarrow Y$ has a continuous adjoint $Z\rightarrow C(X,Y)$. There is always a finest topology with this property. It is aptly called the *natural topology*. The adjunction in the other direction is more problematic, however, and in general there is no coarsest *admissible* topology on $C(X,Y)$.

Comment: I just said it was relevant, which I believe it is (to get **everything** to work nicely, specifically the adjunction in the other direction).

Comment: Search for "exponential law" in this forum. See also https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in [1].
$\newcommand{\Top}{\mathbf{Top}} % topological spaces$

- Yes, the compact open topology.
- No. A topological space $X$ is *exponentiable* if the functor $-\times X: \Top\to\Top$ has a right adjoint $(-)^X$. [1] shows that $X$ is exponentiable iff it is [*core compact*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces#corecompactness). If $X$ is Hausdorff, $X$ is core compact iff it is locally compact.
- Again, no. What matters is $X$, not $Y$.

[1]: *Escardó, Martín; Heckmann, Reinhold*, Topologies on spaces of continuous functions., Topol. Proc. 26(2001-2002), No. 2, 545-564 (2002). [ZBL1083.54009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1083.54009).

Answer (score 1):

Q: *Given two topological spaces, $X$ and $Y$, is there a natural space of continuous functions from one space to the other?*

A: Yes.  It is the collection of *all* continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$.  (From another vantage point, one sometimes encounters an arbitrary set $X$, a topological space $Y$, and a set ${\cal F}$ of functions from $X$ to $Y$.  One can then ask, What minimal topology will make all the functions in ${\cal F}$ continuous?)

Since you call this collection of functions a ``space'', I suspect you might be looking to find out whether there is some natural (topological?) structure on this collection.  If so, yes, there is: [**the compact-open topology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology).  I think it leads to a general answer to your question about regarding a homotopy as a continuous (in some sense) mapping from $[0, 1]$ to the set of continuous mappings from $X$ to $Y$.  An efficient source to grasp this from is the book "Homotopic topology" by Fomenko, Fuchs, and Gutenmaher.