# Algebraic topology terminology

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology

This is a question about mathematical writing.

I'm not super familiar with algebraic topology, but in something I'm writing I need to talk about abstract simplicial complexes, their geometric realizations as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$,
and topological spaces that are homeomorphic to those geometric realizations.

So I have, if you like, abstract simplicial complexes, geometric simplicial complexes, and topological simplicial complexes. Just calling them all ``simplicial complexes'' seems unnecessarily confusing, but throwing in the qualifying adjectives everywhere makes the material hard to read, or at least unpleasant, in a different way.  Is there a good solution to this problem?

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Comment: Check out this great answer, with a historical bent: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70634/why-algebraic-topology-is-also-called-combinatorial-topology/80239#80239

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few suggestions.

Regarding *geometric simplicial complexes*: Sometimes people use terminology like *polyhedra* or *polytope*. That seems to work fine as long as you are staying away from a discussion of classical polyhedra.

Regarding *topological simplicial complex*: According to the definition you wrote, a topological space $X$ is a topological simplicial complex if there merely *exists* a homeomorphism from $X$ to a geometric simplicial complex. That usage feels off base to me. I would have expected that a specific choice of such a homeomorphism must be part of the structure of a topological simplicial complex. There is adjective for that concept as you wrote it, rather than a noun: $X$ is *triangulable* if such a homeomorphism exists. Also, sometime writers refer to a specific choice of such a homeomorphism as a *triangulation* of $X$, or a *simplicial structure* on $X$, or something like that (c.f. Hatcher's terminology of a $\Delta$ complex structure, which is a bit more general than a simplicial structure).

In general, another thing that happens is that a writer will make a choice, reserving the bare terminology *simplicial complex* for one of the more specialized cases. A combinatorist or a category theorist might reserve that bare terminology for an abstract simplicial complex. On the other hand someone writing a basic geometric topology textbook might reserve that bare terminology for a topological space $X$ equipped with a choice of triangulation (for example Moise's textbook *Geometric Topology in Dimensions 2 and 3*).

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot!